# How to associate a user with a comment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am only allowing signed in users to post a comment, but when posting a comment, how do I get it to say that the currently signed in user posted it?

My COMMENTS create looks like this

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

And this is the comments form

```
<div class="container">
    <% if signed_in? %>
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :username %>
        <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :comment %>
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit "Submit Comment" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
<% else %>
<p> <em>You must be signed in to comment</em> </p>
<% end %>
</div>
```

And this is what the comments look like afterward

```
<h5><em>
        <%= comment.commenter %> posted 
        <% if comment.created_at > Time.now.beginning_of_day %>
        <%="#{time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at)} ago"%> 
        <% else %>
        <%= comment.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %> 
        <% end %>

    </em></h5>

    <p>
        <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.post, comment],
        method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
    </p>
```

I'm not entirely sure how to get it to remember that the current_user posted it. Will I have to associate my comments not only to posts but with users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in either of two places. In your form, when you do `post.comments.build`, you could pass in the current user as the poster: `post.comments.build(commenter: current_user)`. Or, you could put it in the `create` action, like so:

```
@comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
@comment.commenter = current_user
@comment.save
```